# Add a new exact element on click of a button using react-redux

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I am new to the `react-redux.` So, I have following markup

```
<div className="questionLevelIndication">
                    <span className="levelIndicatorBtn backgroundColorForLow">
                        1
                    </span>
                    <label className="levelIndicationLabel">
                        Low Maximum 6
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="row topMargn">
                    <div className="questionRow">
                        <div className="rowContent borderRight text-center ">1</div>
                        <div className="rowContent fontStyle borderRight">
                            <label type="text">Select from </label>
                            <select value="" className="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start selectId techDrop  margin-left-10">
                                <option value="">None Selected</option>
                                <option value="">Abc </option>
                                <option value="">PQR </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="rowContent borderRight">
                            <div className="fontStyle">
                                <span>Select Questions Type</span>
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm margin-left-10 typeBtn">some Type</button>
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm margin-left-10 typeBtn">Nothing Type</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="rowContent">
                            <div className="fontStyle">
                                Number Of Questions
                                <select value="" className="numberDropdown selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start selectId quesSDrop margin-left-10">
                                    <option value="">01</option>
                                    <option value="">02</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="rowContent">
                        <span className="">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm standard-btn-50">Reset</button>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm standard-btn-50 margin-left-10">+</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here, are three type of the fields:

1.low
2.medium
3.hard

for every field there is going to be a same HTML structure.

So, I have used the same code thrice. There is a plus button in each catagory, now, on click of this button the respected row will get replicated one time for first user, with max 6 rows.

So, same goes for the medium and hard as well. I have a few questions like:

1.How can I have have only one html structure that will render for three categories?

2. If user clicks on the plus button then how do I add that exact row after the first one with change of ID's?
3. How to get the value of each added new row with the previous one as well?
4. If a user has removed that row then how do I remove that ?
5. Where do I add a scrollbar because maximum 20 rows may get added?

Can anyone please give me any hint? It will be really helpful.

Comment: use map to render the multiple elements and state variable to maintain the count of no of rows in each type

Answer (score 4):

1.How can I have have only one html structure that will render for three categories?

You can save your three categories in three let constants, like:

```js
render() {
  let theFirstItem = <div> Your 1 st content here </div>
  let theSecondItems = <div> Your 2 nd content here </div>
  let theThirdItems = <div> Your 3 rd content here </div>

  return(
    <div>
      <div>{theFirstItem}</div>
      <div>{theSecondItem}</div>
      <div>{theThirdItem}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

2.If user clicks on the plus button then how do I add that exact row after the first one with change of ID's?

Sample code:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";

class details extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      rows: []
    };
    this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let r1 = <div> Your template code here </div>;
    var rows = this.state.rows;
    rows.push(r1);
    this.setState({
      rows: rows
    });
  }

  addRow() {
    var rows = this.state.rows;
    let rPlus = <div> Added row here </div>;
    rows.push(rPlus);
    this.setState({
      rows: rows
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.rows.map(row => (
            <tr>
              <td>{row}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.addRow}>Your Plus Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default details;
```

3.How to get the value of each added new row with the previous one as well?

Given that you didn't specify when you want to get the value of each added row, I assume that you want to save users' input when they click plus button. If so, you need either have a form or handle the value by adding onClick function to submit all values of a row. I suggest you save all values of the current editing row to this.state value, then once user submit them, you can save them to redux state or directly save in your database.

For example:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    value: ""
  };
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
onChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
  //do not forget this, or user cannot modify the value.
}
```

And in HTML, if you use input:

```html
<input 
  name="searchContent" 
  value={this.state.yourValue} 
  onChange={this.onChange} 
/>
```

Then add a `onClick` function to save the current this.state value to whatever you want.

4.If a user has removed that row then how do I remove that ?

You have to save the indexes of the rows when you save all value of a row. And use :

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

to delete the row from "rows" array which I specified for Q2.

5.Where do I add a scrollbar because maximum 20 rows may get added?

Sample HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Example</title>

<!-- CSS -->
<style>
/* Force scrollbars onto browser window */
body {
margin-bottom: 200%;
}

/* Box styles */
.myBox {
border: none;
padding: 5px;
font: 24px/36px sans-serif;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
}

/* Scrollbar styles */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px olivedrab;
border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 10px;
background: yellowgreen; 
box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
background: #7bac10;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="myBox">
Your rows here.
Your rows here.
Your rows here.
...
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can find other styles from this page: 
[Scroll Bar](https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_scrollbars.cfm)

Hope my answer will help you.